# Compressing Grayscale 8-bit PNG Sequences with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, codec, grayscale

I typically deal with many high-resolution PNG sequences, many of which are RGB (24-bit) or entirely grayscale (8-bit). Because adjacent frames in the sequences are very similar, it is important that I compress them losslessly using a codec that supports inter-frame compression. I've used libx264 to compress the RGB 24 bit sequences with decent success (specifically `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i out%04d.png -c:v libx264rgb -qp 0 out.mp4`), and while I can do the same for the grayscale images, I'm wondering if there's a better codec to use in that case given that there's only one channel instead of three.

**Is there a better alternative codec than libx264 for grayscale png sequences specifically? If so, why is it better? If not, why is libx264 the best in both cases?**

Comment: What's your primary requirement - file size, encoding speed, compatibility?

Comment: @Gyan, I'd like to reduce file size as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

libx264 and libx265 both have lossless modes, are inter-frame, and support the gray pixel format.

## libx264

libx264 supports the gray pixel format (see `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264`), so using that instead of libx264rgb may be a more appropriate choice for the grayscale inputs:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i out%04d.png -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -preset veryslow out.mp4
```

## libx265

Worth trying to compare with libx264, but it will be much slower to encode (especially if you use a slow preset):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i out%04d.png -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 out.mp4
```

## others

ffv1, huffyuv, ffvhuff, qtrle are all lossless and support gray pixel format(s), but these are are all intra-frame.

Comment: Compressing the following files with your first libx264 command doesn't seem lossless. When I extract them with `ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -start_number 0 out_depth%04d.png`, the resulting files I get have different pixel values (also, the output is 24bit instead of 8bit). Am I doing something wrong? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YnnJgTT-YTcmxBhFEitr63n2fxZrQrCN

Comment: @jippyjoe4 You forgot to enable lossless mode with `-crf 0` or `-qp 0`.

Comment: I did use -qp 0 in the encoding command (I ran your line exactly as in your answer). Using it in the decoding command I specified in my comment (`ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -qp 0 -start_number 0 out_depth%04d.png`) results in the following warning: `Codec AVOption qp (Constant quantization parameter rate control method) specified for output file #0 (out_depth%04d.png) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.`.

Comment: Also, running `ffmpeg -qp 0 -i out.mp4 -start_number 0 out_depth%04d.png` results in `Codec AVOption qp (Constant quantization parameter rate control method) specified for input file #0 (out.mp4) is not a decoding option.`, so I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 1) The `-qp 0` is intended for MP4 output when encoding with libx264, not for the PNG outputs. 2) Option placement matters. You are attempting to apply `-qp 0` to the input. Placement should be as follows `ffmpeg [global options] [input options] input [output options] output`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. I made a video here showing exactly what I'm doing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezurM5y-rfE&feature=youtu.be
I don't understand why the output files aren't the same as the inputs.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 Looks like pixel format conversion is possibly occurring, although I am unable to try it myself right now. Seeing gray in the list of supported pixel formats I assumed it would stay within gray. Try libx265 instead.

Comment: Thank you, I should have tried that sooner. libx265 seems to work perfectly. The output is 8-bit and the files are identical. Although I still don't know why libx264 wouldn't work.

Comment: @llogan would you have suggested other codec(s) if the OP's main objective was (decode) speed, as opposed to file size?